# Not able to simulate MMWormhole app in simulator

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

MMWormhole as listed here (https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) is used to share data across iPhone watch kit extension and iPhone app. But while trying to run the example given in the above project, the expected behaviour of passing data is not being simulated.

I am running the watch kit extension target i get the data transfer to be simulated .

Note: I tried doing the same idea on my own app and found the same problem and thus posting for MMWormhole.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Everything works properly in the Xcode 6.2 GM release.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.2 version

Comment: You have to use App Groups. That's the basic mechanism of the share.

Comment: Yes! I did create a app group and added it to the app-groups section of the capabilities of both iOS and watch kit app extension. Still its not helping !

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled app groups and changed the identifier in the example app to match yours? From the MMWormhole README:

> The MMWormhole Example app will only work with your shared App Group identifiers and Entitlements and is meant purely for reference

Comment: Can you please elaborate ! How do i go about changing the App Group identifiers and Entitlements

Comment: You can turn on App Groups by clicking on your targets and selecting the Capabilities tab. You'll find it near the bottom of the list.

Comment: @bgilham enabled app groups but it's still not working. what do I need to do?